# O SUB-MENU desapareceu CSS

Tags: css

O submenu esta escondido no menu; preciso dessa ajudinha, aqui esta o codigo do menu e submenu.

```css
.menu.superior{
        background-repeat:no-repeat;
    height:225px;
    margin-left:-185px;
    margin-right:-184px;
    display:block;
    background-color:rgba(0,0,0,0);
    }
    
    /* Adicionando Icones por Menu */
     #cabecalho{
    background:url("https://cdn.awsli.com.br/119/119688/arquivos/Sem Titulo-1.jpg");
    background-position:top center;
    background-repeat:repeat-x;
    background-position-y:490px;
    /*height:1013px;*/
    }
    
    .pagina-inicial #cabecalho .menu .nivel-um{ display:inline-block;  padding-left:5px; }
    .pagina-inicial #cabecalho .menu .engloba-topo:hover .nivel-um{display:inline-block;}
    .menu.superior > ul{ text-align: center; }
    
    
    /* Fim do Menu Interno */
    
    /*ESCONDENDO UNS ERROS */
    
    
    /* Menu do Template */
    .menu.superior .nivel-um>li{ 
        list-style-type: none;
        margin: 0;
        padding: 0;
        overflow: hidden;
    }
    
    .menu.superior .nivel-um>li{ 
        border: 0 none;
        float: center;
        margin-left:5px;
        padding: 15px;
        text-align: center;
        display:block; 
        background-color:#000;
        opacity:0.7;
        height:73px;
        width:127px;
        margin-top:8px;
    }
    .menu.superior .nivel-um>li:hover{ margin-top: 0;}
    
    
    .menu.superior .nivel-dois, .menu.superior .nivel-dois, .menu.superior .nivel-um li:hover .nivel-dois{ display: contents; position:absolute; }
    
    .pagina-login .menu.superior, .pagina-busca .menu.superior, .pagina-carrinho .menu.superior{ display: relative; }
    
    .menu li.com-filho{
     position:inherit;
    }
    .menu.superior .nivel-dois{
    display:none;
        position:absolute;
        top:103px;
        text-align:center;
        left:auto;
        margin-left:-35px;
            min-width:auto;
        width:140px;
        /*background:#fff;*/
    
    }
    .menu.superior .nivel-dois a{
    font-weight:bold;
        color:#564119;
        margin-top:3px;
        background:#fff;
        width:157px;
    }
    .menu .nivel-dois, .menu .nivel-tres, .menu.lateral .nivel-um>li>a{
    background:transparent;
    }
```

Preciso de ajuda.

Link: https://www.lojaviral.com.br/

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Existem validadores de CSS online (o da W3 por exemplo) assim como *linters* para os IDE's mais conhecidos. Rapidamente lhe devem dar uma ideia dos erros de CSS que o seu código tem, assumindo que são erros de escrita. Se está a tentar fazer algum estilo ou posicionamento em CSS e não está a conseguir edite a sua pergunta e torne claras as suas duvidas.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seu problema está em que as `li` no `ul` com a classe `.nivel-um` do menu está com `overflow: hidden;` no arquivo `avancado.css`:

```
.menu.superior .nivel-um>li{ 
    list-style-type: none;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    overflow: hidden;
}
```

Isso faz com que o elemento esconda tudo que ultrapassar seus limites. Para resolver o problema, exclua o `overflow: hidden;`, ficando assim:

```
.menu.superior .nivel-um>li{ 
    list-style-type: none;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}
```

Comment: Muito Obrigado.

Comment: No teu submenu o item "TODAS" não é clicável?